# Problem with server JSP GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I want run JSP code in GeoServer 2.2.3.  I put page JSP in `data_dir/www` but it did not run, however an HTML page runs fine in the same folder.

Comment: I think you need to do settings with tomcat for that and why you are trying to run jsp from geo-server?? Are you able to run that jsp from tomcat?

Comment: Geoserver containt server jetty, jsp can run from server jetty!! In geoserver 2.0.0, i can run jsp in server jetty, but in geoserver 2.2.3 (lastest version) i can't!???

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure when, but the location for the Jetty root has changed somewhere inbetween version 2.0.0 and 2.1.4. Try placing your jsp files in `<geoserver dir/>/webaps/` folder

Comment: Thanks for reply! But <geoserver dir>/webapps/ dir not run too!! :(